# .wbp extension in corporate level websites ('index.wbp' etc)

Tags: web-services, web-applications, webserver, web

There are a lot of big companies' public sites which use '.wbp' suffix at their webpages instead of html, aspx, jspx... What technology is behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particular websites you are interested in are built with proprietary [Actis Wunderman](https://www.actis.ru/en)'s WebBuilder CMS where *.wbp* stands for WebBuilder page. Here is a [description of WebBuilder system](http://web.archive.org/web/20101026090410/http://actis.ru/en/webbuilder/index.wbp).

You can setup a web-server to handle requests for custom extensions. All you need is to change request mapping.

Answer (score 0):

you may find it usefull

```
http://filext.com/faq/fake_file_extensions.php
```

and this

```
http://www.zorched.net/2006/01/20/aspnet-web-application-without-aspx-extension/
```

Comment: Ok, i understood about fake extensions, thanks. Actually I knew about this opportunity) But what are the chances that several companies had decided to use same fake extension - 'wbp'? Maybe it is some CMS that use 'wbp' as extension by default?